# Overriding Interface Fields

Tags: vb.net, class, interface, properties, overriding

New coder here so I apologise in advance if this is really obvious question. I have made an Interface called IState, and one of the properties of IState is Outputs, which is a list of IStates. I plan  on having about 4 different classes which will implement the IState interface. However, on 2 of the classes, I want to be able to Override the Outputs property, and have it as a list of strings, instead of a list of IStates. Is this possible, or is there a clever way to work around it?

Below is the code for IState.

```
Public Interface IState
    Property Name As String
    Property Outputs As List(Of IState)
    Property OnScreen As String
    Sub Update()
    Sub OnSpace()
End Interface
```

Comment: You're not talking about overriding at all. Overriding occurs when a member that is declared `Overridable` is implemented in a base class and then a new implementation is provided in a derived class. You can't override interface members because they have no implementation to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

What you're suggesting cannot be done, even with a property rather than a field. If your interface declares a member of a specific type then any type that implements that interface must implement that member of that type. You could make your interface generic like this:

```
Public Interface IState(Of T)
    Property Name As String
    Property Outputs As List(Of T)
    Property OnScreen As String
    Sub Update()
    Sub OnSpace()
End Interface
```

and then any class that implemented that interface would get to specify what `T` was itself.  You'd run into a recursive issue if you wanted `T` to be that interface though, so I think that you may just out of luck.  You're basically asking to be able to implement an interface without implementing it. The answer to that is no, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

An interface is a specification of properties, methods, and events and their signatures (property type, method argument order and type, etc.).  You can use generics as a way to dynamically define a new interface and generic interfaces do have there uses, but you run into the issue that an `IGeneric(Of Type1)` is not the same as an `IGeneric(OF Type2)`.

With out knowing you specific usage requirements other than that you want to allow the `Outputs` property to be either a `List(Of IState)` or `List(Of String)`, it is difficult to conceive an all purpose solution.

One all purpose solution is to reduce the constraint on the `Outputs` type to it only being an [IList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=netframework-4.7.2).  This would allow you to return either a `List(Of IState)` or `List(Of String)`.  However, the implementation would also be free to return any other type that implements the IList interface.

```
Public Interface IState
    Property Name As String
    Property Outputs As IList
    Property OnScreen As String
    Sub Update()
    Sub OnSpace()
End Interface
```

A different approach is to maintain strong restrictions on the `Outputs` type by moving it to a new interface type that inherits from `IState` without an `Outputs` property.

```
Public Interface IState
    Property Name As String
    Property OnScreen As String
    Sub Update()
    Sub OnSpace()
End Interface

Public Interface IOutputString : Inherits IState
    Property Outputs As List(Of String)
End Interface

Public Interface IOutputIState : Inherits IState
    Property Outputs As List(Of IState)
End Interface
```

This has the benefit that you can pass a class instance that implements any of the above interfaces as an `IState`.  If you need to access the Outputs property, then you could try to cast the value to one of IOutputXXXX types.